# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined JSF Primefaces (h:head included)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a simple JSF page displaying a text editor from primefaces ([Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/textEditor.xhtml)).

However, the text editor is not displayed. When I inspect it (F12 in chrome), I see multiple errors, the first one is:

```
core.js.xhtml:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at Object.resolveUserAgent (core.js.xhtml:2)
at Object.init (core.js.xhtml:2)
at core.js.xhtml:2
```

The others are Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '*Tag from Primefaces*' of undefined.

I read those questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588126/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-in-jsf-primefaces) / [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553417/primefaces-css-looknfeel-missing-and-js-uncaught-reference-error-primefaces), but **I do have a  `<h:head>`**.

What am I missing?

My page (index.xhtml):

```
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:textEditor value="#{textEditorController.text}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{textEditorController.submit}"/>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MusiglabelWEB</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I use muliple projects (WEB, JPA, EJB, EAR), if that matters.

Included Libraries in WEB Project:

Primefaces 6.1 (Downloaded [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces))

Bootsfaces 1.1.1 (Downloaded [here](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/releases))

Comment: What's the stack of the first js error?

Comment: what if you remove `<h:outputScript library="js" name="script.js" />`? And what JS do you see loaded in the browser console... Please do some investihation...

Comment: stack added.
Removing my own script.js doesn't change it.
Im not sure how to view the JS loaded, but if you mean those listed in the "Sources" tab: jquerry.js, jquerry-plugins.js, texteditor.js. components.js, core.js

Comment: So, you build PrimeFaces from source? Or how exactly is it integrated in your project?

Comment: Check on the Network tab if those js files load successfully, jquery in particular.

Comment: Ok, checked it. Following JS files are being loaded:
jquery.js, jquery-plugins.js, components.js, script.js

Comment: Integrated in eclipse: On the WEB Project I added the jars from the given downloads to the Java Build Path.

Comment: Screenshot of the Network tab: http://imgur.com/C6QaXvG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces and JQuery: resource ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390734/primefaces-and-jquery-resource-ordering)

Comment: Though that problem is supposed to be fixed in BootsFaces 1.1.0... Anyway, check if the problem goes away if you remove BootsFaces. If it does, then you should create an issue on their tracker.

Comment: Removed BootsFaces but the problem stayed.

Comment: if you use commandXXX components a form is always needed

Comment: Thats true, forgot that. Not the cause of the problem, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in PrimeFaces, I registered it [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2345). It manifests when a p:textEditor is the first of PrimeFaces components in the final view.

To work around the bug simply add some other component before it, you can make it not rendered, so it won't affect your page otherwise:

```
<p:inputText rendered="false" />
<p:textEditor />
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the same problem.
solved with importing both jquery and jquery ui like following

```
...
    <h:head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</h:head>
...
```

Comment: Bad solution (version wise) and error prone in other pages